# How to get online friends who are currently using my application through Facebook sdk android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I created an android application which has Facebook login and I have been trying to get my friends who are currently using my application. This means I want to get my friends who are currently online  in my app. I tried multiple ways and all of them are giving me the online_presence as "offline" every time though some of my friends are online. Some of the methods I tried are

```
1. Added permissions (user_onlinepresence, friends_online presence, user_status) in app-appdetails- configure app center permissions. ----didn't work.
```

2.SELECT uid, name, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 1234)&access_token=xxxxxxtokenxxxxx&method=GET--- gives me empty data(though many of friends using my app are online.)

I googled so much about this. But didn't get any solution which is working. I request you all to help me in this issue and would provide a solution which could work for me.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I would be interested in knowing how you did it.

Comment: unfortunately i stopped working on android. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of GraphRequest is very simple, just add this method:

```
private String[] getUserContacts(){

    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/friends",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray rawContactsData = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        contacts=new String[rawContactsData.length()];
                        for (int j = 0; j < rawContactsData.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject item = rawContactsData.getJSONObject(j);
                            contacts[j]=item.getString("id");
                        }
                        Log.d("Contacts","ala"+rawContactsData);
                        getCalendarData();
                    }catch (JSONException e){

                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
    return contacts;
}
```